# How to re-apply filters in Vaadin 8 Grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I've added filters to my Grid such as the following:

```
filterTextField.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
        myListDataProvider.addFilter(
                columnName, 
                value-> value.toLowerCase().contain(filterTextField.getValue()));
    });
```

This sets and applies the filter. However later I perform an action on the grid which necessitates a reload of the items such that:

```
grid.setItems(reloadItemsDueToAction());
```

When I do this the `filterTextField` is of course still populate and the grid is reloaded, however the problem is that I don't know how to re-apply the filters that were set in the `ListDataProvider` so that the grid is once again filtered according to the `filterTextField`. The filters should still be set in the ListDataProvider but how do I apply them in the grid?

Comment: Usually you can call [`dataProvider.refreshAll()`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.5/com/vaadin/data/provider/DataProvider.html#refreshAll--) which triggers a `DataChangeEvent`, the grid receives it and updates the UI. How does your data change to require a call to `grid.setItems(...)`?

Comment: Calling refreshAll() doesn't work. An example action would be one where the data is transferred from one database table to another depending on the details of the action, in which case it's easier just to reload the grid. The problem is that when I reload the grid the filters are still visible in the TextField but are no longer applied on the grid.

Comment: Are you using the data provider to retrieve the data from the DB or something else? I feel it'd be easier if you could provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that currently (8.1.5) it is possible only by setting the DataProvider and filters again, for example:

```
private ListDataProvider<Entity> ldp
   = new ListDataProvider<>(getGridItems()); // initial grid data

// then somewhere update grid & re-apply filters

SerializablePredicate<Entity> filter = ldp.getFilter(); // store filter
ldp = new ListDataProvider<>( getGridItems() ); // new ldp with fresh data
grid.setDataProvider(ldp); // instead of setItems()
if(filter!=null) ldp.addFilter(filter); // re-apply stored filter
```

The same fashion applied earlier also with `Table/Container`.

If you use `setItems()` i guess `Grid` is not anymore using the previous `DataProvider` and setting filters to previous `DataProvider` will not propagate to `Grid`. I do not know if it is wise but if you really need to use `setItems()` then maybe something like this:

```
ListDataProvider<Entity> ldp = ((ListDataProvider<Entity>)g.getDataProvider());
SerializablePredicate<Entity> filter = ldp.getFilter();
grid.setItems(getGridItems());
ldp = ((ListDataProvider<Entity>)g.getDataProvider());
if(filter!=null) ldp.addFilter(filter);
```

Tested both with multiple filters.

Answer (score 0):

Create TextField as filter on grid, preserve the values in map, override hasValue ,add after fetching data to the grid